# Backup/Versioning AWS AppSync from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-appsync

As I'm using AppSync for my project, I was wondering **if there is a way of versioning AppSync API from the console** as I have already made the Schema for it. I couldn't find a way to do it for **Schema as it is prone to unintentional edits**. Versioning is available for AWS Lambda from Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no version in the AWS AppSync console or API at the moment.  I am keeping my schema as part of my source code file and versioning it in `git`, with the rest of the project artefacts.

If you are using [amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/), the schema will be generated / edited on the client side and pushed by Amplify CLI.  If you are editing directly in the console, you can export and save your schema from the "Schema" tab (and you can chose between schema.json and schema.graphql formats)

Answer (score 1):

AppSync currently does not support API versioning yet, but it is something that will be considered for the long term road map.

Comment: has there been progress around this?